# Installing packages from requirements.txt in github repo

Tags: python, github

I am trying to pip install packages from a requirements file I generated using pipreqs.

However I keep encountering this error message:

```
fatal: repository 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EmmS21/SpringboardCapstoneBoxingPredictionWebApp/master/code/requirements.txt/' not found
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EmmS21/SpringboardCapstoneBoxingPredictionWebApp/master/code/requirements.txt 'C:\Users\User\Documents\src\pandas' Check the logs for full command output.
```

this is the code I wrote:

```
pip install -e git+https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EmmS21/SpringboardCapstoneBoxingPredictionWebApp/master/code/requirements.txt#egg=pandas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-r` to install requirements. `git+` is only needed if you are trying to install a package from a git repo, however you have a direct link to the file, so remove that.

```
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EmmS21/SpringboardCapstoneBoxingPredictionWebApp/master/code/requirements.txt
```

Comment: Yeah, you can do this if you wanna install just the requirements

Comment: Which is what the question is about, no?

Comment: True true, I was just considering the possibility he was trying to install the repo as a package considering he was using `-e`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `pip install -e` you can't specify the `requirements.txt` file directly. `pip` is attempting to clone a copy of the repository and having the `/master/code`etc. makes it an invalid git repository URL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `/` in the is causing the problem `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EmmS21/SpringboardCapstoneBoxingPredictionWebApp/master/code/requirements.txt`

And you can install it via: `pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EmmS21/SpringboardCapstoneBoxingPredictionWebApp/master/code/requirements.txt`